# JUnit Test for a Generic class

Tags: java, unit-testing, generics, junit

How can I test a generic class, like for example Stack.class from java.utils with junit?(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) Is it enough to test it only for one Type, like Integer, because the class treats 2 different Types the same way?

Comment: _because the class treats integers of 2 different Types_ What do you mean?

Comment: Generally behaviour of generic classes are the same for any given generic type so its okay to test it for only one type.

Comment: Well, hopefully you don't need to test Stack, because Oracle already tested that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you only need to test it for a single type, everything else is handled by the compiler/runtime